# How to get Class<?> object of a generic type

Tags: java, generics

I have a static method which will return a custom type based on the type of the class,

```
public class GenericMethod {

    public static <T> T returnGeneric(Class<T> clazz) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now, I want to pass a class with a generic type in to it,

```
CustomType<String> type = GenericMethod.returnGeneric(CustomType.class);
```

Only problem is that the above statement gives and unchecked conversion warning.

I tried the workaround `new CustomType<String>().getName()` which is also not solving the problem.

Is there a right way to it, or the only solution is to use `@SuppressWarnings` ?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would/should like to try is this:

```
CustomType<String> type = GenericMethod.returnGeneric(CustomType<String>.class);
```

Unfortunately, because of type erasure there is no difference between `CustomType<A>.class` and `CustomType<B>.class`, hence this syntax is not supported by Java.

So my $.02: what you are asking for is not possible, so hang on to the @suppresswarnings...

Comment: Why, as I said: "hence this syntax is not supported by Java"

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use a wrapper method and place all your warnings in a single place.

And the term "unchecked" means that the compiler does not have enough type information to perform all type checks necessary to ensure type safety.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can't do it because of type erasure.

In practice though ;) you can do it because the information is actually in the .class files.
The easiest way I know of is [using Spring's `GenericTypeResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/GenericTypeResolver.html).

Have a look at it.

Comment: There is no difference between theory and practice. You are misunderstanding what type erasure is. And class metadata is not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

As you said @Simeon "In theory you can't do it because of type erasure".
You can use it only if you have subclasses of `CustomType`:

```
class GenericMethod {

  public static <T> T returnGeneric(Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
      return  clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    CustomeType<String> ct = returnGeneric(StringCustomeType.class);
    System.out.println(ct);
  }
}

class StringCustomeType extends CustomeType<String> {
}

class CustomeType<T> {
}
```